# SSIS - Script Task Check if Subfolder Exists

Tags: sql, ssis

I want to check if sub-folder exists or not. If exists, move on. If not exists go to next task.

My sub-folder is "C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3" I want to check if Folder3 is exists or not.

I worked on it. Create 2 variables

1> FolderPath = C:\Folder1\Folder2

2> FolderExists = Boolean = False

Script Task
ReadOnlyVariable = @FolderPAth
ReadWriteVariable = @FolderExists

Following script I add in edit script

```
    Dim DirExists As String

    DirExists = Dir(CStr(Dts.Variables("Folder3").Value))

    If DirExists <> "" Then

        Dts.Variables("Folder3").Value = True

    Else

        Dts.Variables("Folder3").Value = False

    End If
```

Can some one correct me please.

Comment: If it doesn't work as hoped for when you run it, what does it do? What errors are you getting?

Answer (score 3):

Based on your comment it doesn't seem like you will care if it is c# of VB so here are steps from beginning to end on how to test Existence of a folder and use it in constrained precedence.

- Define 2 Package Level Variables: FolderPath string, FolderExists boolean
  [image]
- Add Script Task and configure for C# and add FolderPath as a ReadOnlyVariable and FolderExists as a ReadWriteVariable
  [image]
- Click Edit to Edit the script
- Scroll to "#region Namespaces" near the top and add `using System.IO;`
  [image]
- Scroll to the definition of the Main() sub and add the first line after "TODO" below so that the routine becomes:

  ```
  public void Main()
  {
      // TODO: Add your code here
      Dts.Variables["User::FolderExists"].Value = Directory.Exists(Dts.Variables["User::FolderPath"].Value.ToString());

      Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
  }
  ```
- The script task is complete and you should now be able to use the FolderExists variable as the expression for constrained precedence.
- Add your next step in the package and connect with the green success arrow then double click the arrow and set the Constraint Options to evaluate for Expression and Constraint and the expression simply as the FolderExists variable.
  [image]

this solution was fully tested and is operational

Comment: Following is my entire VB script

Comment: Matt, I am new in SSIS and the tips you are giving me is very high level. I couldn't rectify it. 

Current stage is, I am neither getting an error, nor it's moving ahead. package is stopped at script task. It supposed to take next step which is either if it found directory, it need to go for directory or skip that step and move for next step.

If you can elaborate your code it will be very helpful to me. Other way I am asking for ledge.

Comment: being new to Scripting is exciting, normally I would hope to give you tools to figure it out which is what I was doing at this point I need to move on from this question so I updated exact steps of a working and tested method.  Good luck in your learning and do look up some of the links I had originally posted to figure it out.  Note I did use c# I am cleaning up and removing all of the comments that are no longer necessary.